# PassportJS and ExpressJS conditional URL redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using ExpressJS and PassportJS's Facebook strategy to try and perform some conditional redirects on the authentication callback that should be called when certain properties are missing.

My User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  uid: String,
  facebookToken: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  salt: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  birthday: Date,
  gender: String,
  location: String,
  phone: Number,
  verifiedPhone: Boolean,
  interests: {
    culture: Boolean,
    food: Boolean,
    business: Boolean,
    family: Boolean,
    learning: Boolean,
    sports: Boolean,
    movies: Boolean,
    music: Boolean,
    events: Boolean,
    nightlife: Boolean,
    health: Boolean,
    beauty: Boolean,
    fashion: Boolean,
    motoring: Boolean,
    electronics: Boolean,
    groceries: Boolean,
    travel: Boolean,
    decor: Boolean
  },
  weeklyNotifcation: Number,
  weeklyNotificationSent: Number,
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

My Callback:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({uid: req.session.uid}, function(err, user) {
    if(user.email || user.location || user.phone || user.location == undefined) {
      res.redirect('/register');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

The data is stored into mongo after `/auth/facebook` is called. I check the DB against using the session and check to see if it undefined as it will not return the fields since they weren't stored in the DB. The callback fails and returns no data received.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(user.email === undefined || user.location === undefined || user.phone === undefined || user.location === undefined) {
```

is probably what you meant. Also, you should probably check the `err` variable to see if there are errors.